# How to set the angle of an Annotation when use a shared symbol

Tags: arcobjects, c#, annotation

I am creating annotations in an add-in and am trying to rotate the annotation using the Angle field while using a shared symbol, however when I try and set the Angle field directly it always sets back to 0. What is the correct way to set the Angle field?

Most of the properties for shared symbols seem to be set on the ISymbolCollectionElement interface, but Angle is not available.

Here is a simplified snippet of my code. Comments have indicated 3 lines where I have attempted to set the angle to no avail:

```
annotation_fc = //annotation feature class
insert = //annotation insert cursor

//get the shared symbol
var anno_class = annotation_fc.Extension as IAnnoClass;
var symbol = anno_class.SymbolCollection.Symbol[8];

//create the element using the shared symbol
ITextElement element = new TextElement() as ITextElement;
(element as ISymbolCollectionElement).SharedSymbol[symbol_id.Value] = symbol;
(element as ISymbolCollectionElement).Text = anno_text;
(element as ISymbolCollectionElement).Geometry = p;
(element as ISymbolCollectionElement).FlipAngle = 360;

//this Property does not exist, but seems like where I should be setting the angle
(element as ISymbolCollectionElement).Angle = 45; // <<---------------------------------

//does not affect final feature, angle is still 0
//also seems like the wrong way to set the angle
element.Symbol.Angle = 45;  //<<---------------------------------

//creating the annotation feature
var feature_buffer = annotation_fc.CreateFeatureBuffer();
(feature_buffer as IAnnotationFeature2).Annotation = element as IElement;
feature_buffer.Value[feature_id_index] = feature.OID; //this is set in the inserted feature
feature_buffer.Value[status_index] = 0; //this is set in the inserted feature

//this is not set in the inserted feature, angle will be 0
feature_buffer.Value[angle_index] = 45; //  <<---------------------------------

//insert the feature
insert.InsertFeature(feature_buffer);
```

I am using ArcMap 10.5 and this is being executed inside a Tool Add-In.

**EDIT:**

To get around this issue for now I've altered my code in the following ways.

- First I removed the insert cursor. Instead I am using IFeatureClass.CreateFeature() and IFeature.Store(). It should be noted this method will also always set the feature's "Angle" field to 0, just like above.
- After calling Store() I cache the feature OID for later.
- Now I loop back through the features using an Update cursor. The Update cursor allows me to set the "Angle" field without any issues.

This two pass solution is not ideal, but will serve as a temporary workaround.

Comment: I've not used it but the interface [IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#IBasicOverposterLayerProperties4.htm) has a property called `RotationField`, this may be what you are after?

Comment: Thank you for looking into this, but this appears to be a Layer property. I am creating the annotation with an IFeatureClass / IFeature. I don't have layer. 

From the description it also sounds like the RotationField is a string that points to a field on the Annotation FeatureClass which has the angle value, and does not contain an angle value itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is an old question but I had the very same problem and finally figured the solution out by myself.
The OP @danielm was very close. He only oversaw that `ITextElement.Symbol` does not return a *reference* to the symbol but a *copy* of it.
Therefore

```
  element.Symbol.Angle = 45;
```

must be replaced by

```c#
  ITextSymbol textSymbol = element.Symbol;
  textSymbol.Angle = 45;
  element.Symbol = textSymbol;
```

However, this is extremely counterintuitive – thank you Esri for three hours of internet search, trial, and error.